# what to do for 3rd party code which was placed in bridging header before integrating pod file

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

![enter image description here][1]Before using cocoa pods in swift and xCode 6 beta 6 bridging file was used for integrating 3rd party code of obj c. But after making pod file and integrating that 3rd party code library in pod file then what to do for bridging header file and will the pod file library will be available to my code??

Answer (score 2):

It's really not clear what you are asking to be honest. But I will try to answer your question.

The bridging file is for including Objective-C classes that you want to use in your Swift code. It doesn't matter if it's 3rd party code, a Cocoapod, or if you made it yourself.

If you want to access Cocoapod code in your Swift files then just add the Cocoapod as usual (Update Podfile then `pod install`). Then `#import` the header file of the pod class that you want to use in your Swift code.

You should then be able to use the pod in your Swift files using Swift syntax.

For example your bridging header would look like:

```
// My-Bridging-Header.h
#import "AwesomeSauceClassFromAPod.h"
```

Comment: i am asking that before using pod file i have placed .h file in bridge header file so after using pod file will it work as same as before just by putting .h file from cocoa pod because it is outside the scope compared to before condition

Comment: Any classes you import in your bridging header will be available to all your swift files. It's as if you imported those files into all your swift files.

Comment: when  i am opening projectname.xcworkspace in that pod section is different so will that library be able to use from bridge header file which is in project which comes in top section

Comment: I'm almost sure that the answer to your question is Yes. But in your situation why not just run your project, and then try to use a class that is in the pod file from your swift code. It's either going to work or not but it doesn't hurt to just try it out. :-)

Comment: i have tried but build failed and error coming in brige header file that particular ".h" file is not found so it cannot find the header file which was placed using pod which comes in second section in xcworkspace and i have deleted 3rd party library from my project which was initially kept before using pod file because after using pod file it can be used from cocoa pods itself

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ySEQw.png

this type of error is coming please help me to solve this issue
thank you :)